# How to condense nontrivial repetitive code in Python

Tags: python

As a practice I wrote a working python code that gives all permutations of three digits: 1, 2, and 3. (I know it could be done using permutations from itertools). However, upon improving my code I encountered the following problem. As you see below in `combinations` there are three similar lines of code. Of course, there could be arbitrary number of lines depending on the number of objects we are permuting. So I feel like it should be possible to do this using some kind of nested operations. I have spent more than an hour playing with the code, but still have no idea how to do it. Any help?

```
def populate(combination, k):
    for d_k in range(1,4):
        if d_k in combination[:k]:
            continue

        combination[k] = d_k

        yield combination


def combinations(combination):
    for combination_1 in populate(combination, 1):
        for combination_2 in populate(combination_1, 2):
            for combination_3 in populate(combination_2, 3):
                yield combination_3


for combination in combinations([0, 0, 0, 0]): # ignore the first zero
    print(combination)
```

Comment: If you find yourself needing infinitely many nested loops, use recursion instead.

Comment: I have tried, but failed. Is it obvious how to do it in this case?

Comment: Well, you are looking for an algorithm which generates permutations - if you search for "generate permutations algorithm" here or on Google then you should find relevant results. If you find an algorithm and read about it, you can try to implement it, and if it doesn't work or you don't understand the algorithm well enough, then ask here.

Comment: Rosetta Code is a good source for algorithms in different languages.  [Combinations in Python](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#Python)

Comment: The question is not really about permutation. I am using it as an example. Let me clarify. Those three lines differ only in few places. So may one replace them by a single line using something like "regular expressions"? Hope this helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a recursive version of your combinations functions:

```
def combinations(combination,n=1):
    if n>3: yield combination; return
    for combination_n in populate(combination,n): 
        for combined in combinations(combination_n,n+1):
            yield combined
```